# What does x[:,[0,1,2,2]](a kind of splicing) mean in numpy arrays in python? I was executing the following in anaconda

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy using `numpy.ones`, I got this

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.ones((3,3))
print(x)
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]

x[:,[1,1,1,1]]
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: It's [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing)

Comment: You are getting four copies of the first column.

Comment: If you want to analyze what `x[:,[1,1,1,1]]`, or some other operation does, the first thing you should probably do is to use better test data: If the input (and consequently, the output) is all ones, you have no hope whatsoever of making sense of what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x[:, [0,1,2,2]] means you are taking (all the rows of) columns 0,1,2 and 2 and combining them.
Since you have all ones in your data, it is hard to visualize but the following example will help:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])


x[:, [0]]
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])

x[:, [1]]
array([[2],
       [5],
       [8]])

x[:, [2]]
array([[3],
       [6],
       [9]])


x[:, [0, 2, 1, 1]]
out: array([[1, 3, 2, 2],
            [4, 6, 5, 5],
            [7, 9, 8, 8]])
```